# Can tf.contrib.training.batch_sequences_with_states handle input sequences with variable lengths?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, training-data, recurrent-neural-network

I was trying to use `tf.contrib.training.batch_sequences_with_states` to create padded batches of variable length input sequences in order to train an LSTM network.

While reading the documentation I stumbled upon contradicting statements, concerning the capabilities of this function.

Specifically the parameter `input_sequences` is confusing to me.

> `input_sequence` is a dict with values that are tensors with time as first dimension. This time dimension must be the same across those tensors of an example. **It can vary across examples.**
>
> `input_sequences`: A dict mapping string names to Tensor values. **The values must all have matching first dimension**, called value_length. They may vary from input to input
>
> [Source](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/training/batch_sequences_with_states)

How do I supply this function with multiple examples?

### My first attempt

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

batch_size = 10
num_unroll = 4
num_enqueue_threads = 2
lstm_size = 8

seq1 = np.random.rand(8, 8, 2)
seq2 = np.random.rand(16, 8, 2)

sequences = {"seq1": seq1, "seq2": seq2}
context = {"seq1": 0, "seq2": 1}

initial_states = {"c": tf.zeros((lstm_size,), dtype=tf.float32),
                  "h": tf.zeros((lstm_size,), dtype=tf.float32)}

batch = tf.contrib.training.batch_sequences_with_states(
    input_key="key",
    input_sequences=sequences,
    input_context=context,
    input_length=None,
    initial_states=initial_states,
    num_unroll=num_unroll,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    num_threads=num_enqueue_threads,
    capacity=batch_size * num_enqueue_threads * 2,
    make_keys_unique=True
)

inputs = batch.sequences["seq1"]

with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.train.start_queue_runners()
    print(sess.run([inputs]))
```

Executing this code snippet leads to the following error message:

```
ERROR:tensorflow:Exception in QueueRunner: assertion failed: 
[All sequence lengths must match, but received lengths: 8 
 All sequence lengths must match, but received lengths: 16]
```

An example showing how to correctly supply this function with multiple examples of varying input_sequence lengths would be really helpful!

Comment: It doesn't look like it can handle sequences of different lengths.